# WPF Textrimming in horizontally stacked ItemsControl with TextBlocks

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox where each item consists of an ItemsControl that prints TextBoxes.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Collection2}"
                ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource SubItemTemplate}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Width="280"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1}"/>
</Grid>
```

The ItemsControl list gets cut-off abrubtly because I have disabled HorizontalScrollBarVsibility on the ListBox. Now I want to use the TextBoxes TextTrimming property to leave dots at the end of the list, where the text is cut-off and is hidden behind the grid. Illustrated as red dots in the figure below:

[image]

I try to do this by using the following ItemTemplate without any results:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SubItemTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBlock Margin="5, 0, 5, 0"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               Text="{Binding Name}">
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

My question is: How can I achieve TextTrimming functionality on a horizontally stacked list like the figure above?

I've used sample data using Visual Studio Blend with the following structure:

- SampleDataSource (Data Context)

  - Collection1:(Collection)

    - Collection2:(Collection)

      - Name:(String)

**Update 2016-12-13**
I tried setting the texttrimming as an external style and I tried setting the MaxWidth on both the Border, TextBlock and StackPanel (like suggested in comments). Apart from that I also tried wrapping the whole ItemsControl in a TextBlock and put the TextTrimming property on that. None of this gave any results unfortunatly. I do want o simplify the example code that i provided, essentially this is all that is relevant:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="150" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="This is textbox1"/>
        <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="This is textbox2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Which looks like this (where the red dots is visualizing what i want to achieve):

[image]

Now, in this example I could merge the two textblocks and use Run instead, but that would not be applicable on my "real" problem.

**Update 2017-02-24**

This solution was proposed in the comments (note the extra space and margin):

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="TextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, -1, 0"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}" Text="This is textbox1 "/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}" Text="This is textbox2 "/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}" Text="This is textbox3 "/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

I have also tried many different amount of spaces and different values for margin on the textblock without the required result. So the correct answer does not solve my problem fully...

Comment: Have you tried using an external `Style`? Consider following:
`Window.Resource><your TextBlock Style setting Text Trimming Properties>` then reference it in your `DataTemplate` like so: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" Style="{StaticResource <YourStyleKey>}"/>` from what I know the DataTemplate is not part of the VisualTree therefore the style you applied will not be evaluated. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Try swapping your `ItemsPanelTemplate` with something like this - `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>` because I have a feeling you're just not providing a panel boundary to invoke the trimming....but I don't have time to test at the moment. :)

Comment: @XAMlMAX Chris W Thank you for your comments, unfortunatly it did not work. See my update if you're willing.

Comment: I must have been tired when I suggested the border part...but I would expect the maxwidth to work to invoke ellipsis on the StackPanel. Do me a favor, put a hardcoded value on the StackPanel of like `<StackPanel MaxWidth="300"/>` and see if it invokes the ellipsis. If it DOES then we know you're just not getting the ActualWidth of the parent ItemsControl and we can fix that with a direct ref.

Comment: I see, have you tried setting different `ForeColor` on your `TextBlock` to check if it is being applied? @ChrisW. is onto something here. If the `ForeColor` is changing and you still can't see text trimming try setting the `TextBlock` `Width` and see if that triggers it. BTW using a `Grid` as a parent is redundant as the DataTemplate will behave like a `StackPanel` anyway. Try and see for yourself.

Comment: This may sound dumb, but have you tried switching the StackPanel to a DockPanel??  I have had bad luck when it comes to sizes and stackpanels.  I just tested your slimmed down example with a DockPanel and got what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `StackPanel` in your Template to a `DockPanel`.  Even though you set the Max Width of the `StackPanel` the Content inside it will act as if there is no barrier.  A `DockPanel` will force the barrier, and because your items are horizontal, no other changes will  be needed.

Comment: This actually looks like it could work. I have spent all day trying to make a derived custom textbox that binds to a ObservableCollection and creates Run elements from the items. All this so that I can use a single TextBox instead of multiple. Will try your solution tomorrow.

Comment: Amazing that I couldn't find this solution earlier. However, there is one caveat: If the parent control resizes so that it cuts exactly inbetween two TextBlocks, then the ellipses wont be visible at all. Also if it cuts just in the beginning of a TextBlock, only the first one or two ellipses will be visible. I think I need a solution that always shows ellipses regardless of where the parent control cuts the list of names. Going with my custom textbox for this. Although I will keep this as the correct answer since it gives the best answer to my question.

Comment: @micnil, I know this is an old post but I think I might have figured out how to fix the caveat that you mentioned.  If you add a space to the end of the text in the text box and add a negative 1 margin the right side.  I think this will prevent the issue.  Please note that I have tested this

Comment: I appreciate the update. I could however not get it to work with your proposed solution. See updated question